# How to open console automatically when any page loads,without pressing F12 or inspect

Tags: javascript

I trying to open console automatically when any web page loads without using F12 and inspect methods.
Means when we hit any URL console gets open automatically along with loading of page.

Comment: need more info regarding use case. you can open the console and then it will stay open for any other pages loaded in that tab. any other options may be browser specific - depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what browser you're using.  One way of doing this would be to launch Chrome with the '--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs' flag.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open#auto

Comment: I want to do in chrome, bcoz i want to make a app who can automatically fetch error and warnings of given URL from console.

Comment: By executing that script file which contains given URL and and methods which can perform this type of action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that this is possible,

check this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277

which says: "We only allow explicit devtools opening."

you can refer this link for debugging
Also, you may use remote debugging page which opens devtools in a page. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging